# How to display the error page if the form does not contain a tag (.) in python

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, os.system

This is the project

```
from tkinter import *
import os

window = Tk()
window.title("web2video")
window.geometry("330x140+200+100")

photo = PhotoImage(file = "icon.png")
window.iconphoto(False, photo)


urltxt = Label(window, text = "video Url").place(x = 30, y = 10)  
url = Entry(window, width=30)
url.insert(0,"")
url.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=100, pady=10)

def Message():
    if not url.get(): return
    os.system(f"echo ^<html^> > %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<body style=\"background-color:black;\"^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<video controls src=\"{url.get()}\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" ^>^</video^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</body^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</html^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"start %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")

btnSendMessage = Button(window, text="Start", width=20, command=Message)
btnSendMessage.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

I want to close the program or display an error page if the entry does not contain a tag`.`

for example

**This code is wrong, but for clarification**

```
def Message():
    if url.get() not "." : return
    os.system(f"echo ^<html^> > %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<body style=\"background-color:black;\"^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<video controls src=\"{url.get()}\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" ^>^</video^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</body^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</html^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"start %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
```

Comment: `if '.' not in url.get():`? I think you may need to repeat on basics and don't use `os.system`

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module. Avoid os.system.

Comment: Can you give me an example or an idea of a subprocess

Comment: @user17293338, just a little bit of searching will turn up -many- examples of `subprocess`. https://pythonspot.com/python-subprocess/

Comment: Actually, when using `start` like this, `os.system` is pretty OK.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just silly:

```
    os.system(f"echo ^<html^> > %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<body style=\"background-color:black;\"^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^<video controls src=\"{url.get()}\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" ^>^</video^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</body^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
    os.system(f"echo ^</html^> >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\web2video.html")
```

Just do it directly, no escaping, no extra processes:

```
    name = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "/Local/Temp/web2video.html"
    with open(name, 'w') as htmlfile:
        print(f"""\
<html>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<video controls src="{url.get()}" width="100%" height="100%">
</video>
</body>
</html>""", file=htmlfile );
```